# узнать сколько цифр в числе с помощью рекурсии

Tags: c#

задача такая: узнать и вывести сколько цифр в числе например: 123 --> 3 подскажите как это сделать ? мой код работает как-то не правильно выводится только последнее значение.. я конечно понимаю почему так, НО как сделать правильно не знаю....

```
        private static int TestName(int value, int count = 0) 
    {
        if (value<=0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (value >= 0)
        {

            value = value / 10;
            count++;
        }
        
        TestName(value,count);
        
        return count;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static int TestName(int value, int count = 1) 
{
    if (value < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (value < 10)
    {
        return count;
    }
    
    return TestName(value / 10, count + 1);
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое :)

Comment: без рекурсии int cou = $"{value}".Length

Comment: @GiorgiTamazashvili исправил ошибку в коде

Comment: @Виктор задача была про рекурсию, и кстати через рекурсию быстрее отработает по производительности, чем через строку. Через цикл конечно еще быстрее, можно даже через десятичный логарифм, но суть не в этом.

Answer (score 3):

Без дополнительного аргумента. Работает и для положительных и для отрицательных чисел:

```
private static int NDigits(int value) {
    if (-10 < value && value < 10) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 1 + NDigits(value / 10);
}
```

Comment: лови функциональщика!

Comment: Здорово, правильный подход к решению задачи, а не исправление кода в вопросе. Вот как бы всем это привить?

Comment: @aepot, ваш ответ ещё более функциональный чем мой. У вас хвостовая рекурсия, а функциональщики очень это дело любят. Вы часом не функциональщик под прикрытием?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy нет, что вы, никогда ни разу на Erlang ничего не писал. :)

Answer (score 1):

потому что строка `TestName(value,count);` ничего на самом деле не делает. Должно быть `return TestName(value,count);`